# Get Image File Name from Google Colab

Tags: python, image, google-colaboratory, os.path

I'm currently reading some images in from Google Drive in Google Colab and need to check that each image filename corresponds with a value in a pandas dataframe.

My code looks this this right now:

```
for img in os.listdir(path):
    if img in df['column']:
        add image to a folder
    else: 
        add image to other folder
```

It seems that Python is checking to see if the actual *image* is in the dataframe, as opposed to the image name and adds all the images to the other folder. How can I make sure that I'm actually looking at the image *file name* when comparing with the dataframe? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
_ in df[]
```

checks against the index, not value.

Try:

```
if img in df.values
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This seems to have worked!

Comment: Please upvote or mark as answered if it helped :)

Comment: Just did :) -- can't comment yet but marked as best answer